# How to grant permission for a group of users instead of whole organization using /adminconsent endpoint?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

**Background**

I am trying to develop a multi-tenant SaaS application. 
I am trying Admin Consent model of authorization. However, I am not able to figure out scoped destination i.e *how to limit ourselves to a specific group of users in an enterprise rather than all users*.

I believe that not all enterprises might want us to handle all users in the beginning.

**Description**

I am using a `client_credentials` grant for authentication.

The app is meant to read a user's drive data.

Set of permissions that I am asking are:

- `Files.Read.All`
- `Users.Read.All`
- `Sites.Read.All`

When I ask a global admin to grant required permissions i.e, redirecting to 
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=[my_client_id]&state=12345&redirect_uri=[my_redirect_uri]`

As soon as the admin consents to the permission, it is for all the users under that tenant. This is a highly unacceptable situation for an enterprise O365 admin where he/she exposes the entire user's/drive-file's details.

*Is there a way where admin consents on behalf of a particular set/group of users?*

**Note**: Only admins are allowed to consent. I have got suggestions to use *Security groups* or creating *Service account*. Please give some pointers if they are applicable for my use case.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible, it also isn't working the way you think it is.

To clarify, the Admin Consent process isn't consenting on behalf of "all users", it is consenting to your application accessing the tenant. When using Client Credentials, there is no User in context. When an Admin consents to your application, they are granting tenant wide (i.e. admin-level) access to the areas specified in your scopes (in this case, the ability to read any user, view any OneDrive, and read any SharePoint site).

If you want to limit access, you need to use an OAuth Grant like Authorization Code that takes a specific user's credentials. This would ensure your application only has access to the content the user has access to.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Marc. If I am not wrong, I have to promt for user consent then right? My use case is to acces an organizations file data but in a user group scoped way. Is there any way to do so without user intervention?

Comment: No, the AAD v2 Endpoint will not allow you to operate on behalf of a user without consent. You would need to obtain this at least once. For scenarios like this, folks often use a service account (a user account without an associated human). An Admin uses those credentials to consent and obtain the initial Access Token. After that your app simply uses a Refresh Token when it needs to obtain a new token.

Comment: Thanks @MarcLaFleur , so you mean that if the group is made of 1000 people, the admin has to consent 1000 times with his service account credentials ? If not, could you clarify a little bit : with the AAD v2 endpoint, initial access token is obtain for one user after redirection on consent. How do you get the 1000 access tokens at the begining using this service account ?

Comment: No, one of the 1,000 "people" would be the service account. Consent happens once per `user`. If you need to operate on behalf of the 1,000 users individually, you would need to authenticate each of those 1,000.

Comment: How you wire this up really depends on the scenario you are looking to execute. If you want the execute on behalf of an individual user then you need to have that user authenticate. If you want to execute on behalf of the organization, you only need to authenticate the client app it self ("client credentials").

Comment: Thanks @MarcLaFleur. Is it like the service account manages those 1000 users(as a group)? And when a service account consents, I am able to fetch only those 1000 users with /users endpoint.

Comment: I am trying to achieve the above scenario. After consent stage i should be able to fetch details(drive details in my case) for a group of users rather than all users. Also individual user logins are not allowed in my case. Please clarify if Service Account can serve this purpose.

Comment: The "service account" I mentioned is _just a user_ (i.e. first name 'Service', last name 'Account'). This won't allow you to access other user's OneDrives on their behalf, it would only allow you to access them on behalf of the service account. If you need to access User A's drive _as_ User A then you **must** authenticate that user. There is no way around that.

Comment: Great pointer to "Service Account" @MarcLaFleur. I did some investigation on the same. For my use case, there is something called "Site collection administrator" list where i can add the Service Account and required users to scope them out. Please confirm if i am going in a right direction.
Also, the authorization code grant is not applicable for me. Can i go by client_credentials grant to retrieve the token from the Service Account.?

Comment: No. Client Credentials authenticates your client, it does not authenticate a user. As such, if you use Client Credentials, you cannot _not_ operate as (on-behalf) of a specific user. In other words, with Client Credentials your app _is_ the user.